# Disproving a statement by showing that its negation doesn't lead to a contradiction?

Tags: logic, proof-writing, propositional-calculus

Proof by contradiction (or the contradiction rule in logic) uses the first row of the following truth table to assert that if $¬p\Rightarrow{}\textbf{c}$ is true, then $p$ is true:

| $p$ | $¬p$ | $\textbf{c}$ | $¬p\Rightarrow{}\textbf{c}$ | $(¬p\Rightarrow{}\textbf{c})\Rightarrow{}p$ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| T | F | F | T | T |
| F | T | F | F | T |

(let $\textbf{c}$ and $\textbf{t}$ denote a contradiction and tautology respectively)

What I have not seen discussed anywhere is that the second row shows that when $¬p\Rightarrow{}\textbf{c}$ is false, $p$ is false. The potential validity of this argument is further hinted by the equivalence $(¬p\Rightarrow{}\textbf{c})\equiv(p\vee{}\textbf{c})\equiv{p}$, which means $(¬p\Rightarrow{}\textbf{c})\iff{p}$. Is it possible to use this argument form, that is, to show that $¬p\Rightarrow{}\textbf{c}$ is false and conclude that $p$ is false? (opposite of the proof by contradiction, which concludes $p$ is true.)

I feel that this argument form is not completely logical/practical, but I am not 100% why. My guess is that you would have to show $¬p$ does not lead to any contradictions, which is not practical as you would have to cover all (infinite) cases. Or you could show that $¬p$ leads to a tautology, but suddenly I'm not sure how any statement implies a tautology. Any help that would point me in the right direction is appreciated!

Comment: A fun question. :)

Comment: The only way I know of _disproving_ a statement of the form $A\Rightarrow B$ is by showing that $A$ is true and $B$ is false.

Comment: @Cynicrom Proving $¬p\Rightarrow{}\textbf{c}$ is equivalent to proving $¬\textbf{c}\Rightarrow{}p$, which in turn proves $p$ since $\lnot\mathbf c$ is a tautology. But, unlike proof by contradiction, this does not lend itself to a workable technique for solving actual problems. To complete a proof by contradiction, it's enough to reach *one* contradiction. In contrast, it is not clear how you propose that one could possibly be "*showing that its negation doesn't lead to a contradiction*" (i.e. *any* conceivable contradiction), short of proving the statement itself by some other direct method.

Comment: @dxiv So the argument form is impractical, but is it valid nonetheless? I would like to know whether I have committed a fallacy.

Comment: @ryang I just noticed that "does not imply any contradiction" is not the same as "implies a tautology." Oops. Thank you for pointing that out

Comment: Isn't the second row vacuously true? $a \implies b$ so if $\not a$ you stop there. That is the counterintuitiveness of material implication.

Comment: @User5678 You are referring to the statement in the last column. My question is not about the last column, but the inverse of it.

Comment: @Cynicrom As I wrote in my previous comment, your question ultimately amounts to whether proving $p$ is equivalent to proving $true \implies p$. The answer to that is yes, at least in the common formalisms. In that respect, it may not be a fallacy, but it's just a gratuitous restatement of the problem.

Comment: It is called [Double Negation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_negation)... The usual symbol for a *contradiction* is $\bot$; having said that, $\lnot p \equiv p \to \bot$. Thus $\lnot (p \to \bot) \equiv \lnot (\lnot p) \equiv p$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> $$(¬p\Rightarrow{}\textbf{c})\equiv{p}$$

Also: $\quad(\lnot p{\kern.6em\not\kern-.6em\implies}\bot)\;\equiv\;(\lnot p\land\lnot \bot)\;\equiv\;(\lnot p\land\top)\;\equiv\;\lnot p.$

> To conclude that $p$ is false,

> is it possible to **show that $(¬p\Rightarrow{}\textbf{c})$ is false**?

This requires establishing that the antecedent $¬p$ is true (since a false antecedent automatically makes the implication true).

> My guess is that you would have to **show that $¬p$ does not lead to any contradictions**

This also requires establishing that the antecedent $¬p$ is true (since a false antecedent can always lead to a contradiction).

But $¬p$ being true directly means that $p$ is false, without going through the above detours.

> Or you could show that $¬p$ leads to a tautology

This does not entail that $p$ is false; for example: $¬(A\lor\lnot A)\implies\top.$

> I feel that my argument is not completely logical

Summary: your proposal to disprove $p$ by showing that $\lnot p$ leads to no contradiction is not illogical—merely a circuitous way of disproving $p$ by proving $\lnot p.$

Comment: Excellent answer!

Comment: So it is logical to prove $¬p$ by showing $¬(¬p\Rightarrow{}\textbf{c})$, but in order to show $¬(¬p\Rightarrow{}\textbf{c})$, you must show $¬p$ (to show a true antecedent and a false consequent), which is what you wanted to prove in the first place, hence the method reduces to "to show $¬p$ you must show $¬p$", which is just circuitous. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @Cynicrom Not quite: the point is the argument "blah blah, therefore $¬p,$
 therefore $\lnot p{\kern.6em\not\kern-.6em\implies}\bot,$
 therefore $p$
 is false" contains a detour.

Answer (score 0):

As a commenter has pointed out, $\lnot p$ is equivalent to $p \rightarrow \bot$. From this point of view, I would interpret "$\lnot p$ does not lead to a contradiction" as $\lnot (\lnot p \rightarrow \bot)$, which is simply $\lnot \lnot \lnot p$.

This form of triple negation can be simplified to a single negation, of course. The argument is similar to the other answer: if $\lnot \lnot \lnot p$, and we assume $p$, then in particular $\lnot \lnot p$, contradiction. Thus $\lnot p$.

This proof is valid even in intuitionistic logic, and it shows why it can be simplified to just assuming $p$ and finding a contradiction, which is one reason why this method of proof is not the most direct one.

---

But from your statement about "covering all (infinite cases)" I think you might have in mind a different interpretation of "$\lnot p$ does not lead to a contradiction". This could be interpreted as meaning

> "$\lnot \lnot p$" is not provable (in a given system)

Or the (classically) equivalent

> "$p$" is not provable

This does not necessarily imply that $\lnot p$ is provable. For example, in $ZF$ if you take $p$ to be the continuum hypothesis, then neither $p$ nor $\lnot p$ are provable.

If you want to arrive at this second version then you have to work outside the system, so while it's "impractical" it's the only way.